# What the advantages of use_win32_fileio flag on OPENCV build?

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I have researched about use_win32_fileio on Stackoverflow. But, I haven't got the clear answer.
On some reference, I found that use_win32_fileio used on tiff.

Are there any other uses of use_win32_fileio on Opencv?